# DynamoDB Accelerator (DAX) cluster design: Per table cluster OR a single unified cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb-dax

We're having hundreds of DynamoDB tables.

For the performance optimization, we're going to use DynamoDB Accelerator (DAX).

While exploring DAX, I came across two approaches.

1. A unified cache cluster, that can be used for all DynamoDB tables
2. Separate cluster for each DynamoDB table

At a first glance, it seems #2 may be better because of isolation of individual clusters, as none of DynamoDB table's cluster will affect other table's cluster. However, manageability may be bit complex!

Is that correct OR am I missing anything? Which approach would be better and why?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, We have used synthesis of both the approaches to get the merit of both approaches. Sharing it if it can help others!

To elaborate, multiple clusters are being created, and each cluster has been used for different set of DynamoDB tables.

Last note, remember that only one node from cluster handles write operation to DynamoDB and rest of nodes are just read replicas. Hence, while determining set of tables for a cluster, it should be considered.